# How to get and set value from ASPxSpinEdit during LostFocus event.

Tags: javascript, vb.net, devexpress

I have a ASPxSpinEdit that, onblur I would like to truncate any decimals entered. The following code has two issues. I am able to get the value from the box by using the s.ParseValue() method but cannot seem to reassign it after I do any math to the value. The other issue I am having is I cannot seem to leave the box. After the event fires, the cursor is placed back in the box and will not leave. My code is below. Thank you.

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="InventoryBank" Caption="InventoryBank" Width="100px">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxSpinEdit runat="server" NumberType="Float" DecimalPlaces="1" AllowNull="true" AllowMouseWheel="true" AllowUserInput="true" MinValue="-999999999" ID="lblInventoryBank" Value='<%# Bind("InventoryBank") %>' Width="100px" Increment="1" MaxValue="999999999">
            <ClientSideEvents LostFocus="function(s, e) {
                s.ParseValue();
                var truncatedValue = s.GetNumber();
                truncateValue = (truncateValue * 100) / 100;
                }">
            </ClientSideEvents>
        </dx:ASPxSpinEdit>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I suppose I should have gone with my gut here and just circumvented DevExpress altogether. The blow code calls a regular javascript function and the solution from there is rather easy.

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="InventoryBank" Caption="InventoryBank" Width="100px">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxSpinEdit runat="server" NumberType="Float" DecimalPlaces="1" AllowNull="true" AllowMouseWheel="true" AllowUserInput="true" MinValue="-999999999" ID="lblInventoryBank" Value='<%# Bind("InventoryBank") %>' Width="100px" Increment="1" MaxValue="999999999">
            <ClientSideEvents LostFocus="fnTruncateInt" />
        </dx:ASPxSpinEdit>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

And below is the javascript at the top of my page.

```
function fnTruncateInt(s, e) {
    s.SetValue(Math.floor(s.GetValue()));
}
```